# how to show the title of a product that is in the cart of Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I call or show the title of the product that is in the cart in my Woocommerce store?

Currently in the store only one product is allowed in the cart and I would like to show the title of this product on the checkout page.

I am customizing the checkout page.

I have searched with some plugins and codes but I have not been able to show the title of the product where I want

Comment: How are you customizing the chekout page, are you using the form-checkout.php template to do it? Also you say that you have not been able to show the title where you want it. Could you explain where it is that you want the title to be displayed then?

Comment: This is the page I am working with elementor so it is not the original checkout page and that is how it is I have tried the plugin and it brings me the title of the page, 
and I want to show the title of the product that I have in the cart, as the main title of the page

Comment: Since it's a custom page I cant tell you exactly how to do it. But I created a shortcode for you that will echo the name of the product in the cart as a h1 title. You could then use that shortcode in the top div as the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be optimal but what you could do is add a shortcode like this in your functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('cart_item_title_header',function() {
global $woocommerce;
    //Check if cart is empty or not
    if (count(WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0) {
        //Loop trough cart items
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            $product    = $cart_item['data'];
            $name       = $product->get_name();
            $title      = '<h1 class="product-title">' . $name . '</h1>';
        }
        ob_start();
        echo $title;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
);
```

And then add the shortcode in the top div using `[cart_item_title_header]`